# JAVA : Output text from a class to main frame

Tags: java, multithreading, frame

i'm newbie to JAVA.
Trying a simple app, with one thread. I have a frame with a textarea. When i start a thread from one class, i want to output into the textarea, instead of console.
I couldn't find anywhere how to do it. But it should be simple ???
Please help.
Here are the files :

file 01/03 = MaFenetre.java

```
public class MaFenetre
{
public static void main (String args[])
    {
    Fenetre fen = new Fenetre() ;
    fen.setVisible(true) ;

    MyThread test = new MyThread (15) ;
    test.start() ;      
    }
}
```

file 02/03 = Fenetre.java

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class Fenetre extends JFrame// implements ActionListener
{
private JTextArea zoneTexte;

// Constructeur
public Fenetre ()
    {
    setTitle ("Avec deux boutons") ;
    setSize (700, 550) ;

    Container contenu = getContentPane() ;
    contenu.setLayout(new FlowLayout()) ;

    zoneTexte=new JTextArea(5,20);
    contenu.add(zoneTexte) ;

    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

public void AddTxt(String txt)
    {
    this.zoneTexte.append(txt);
    }   
}
```

file 03/03 : MyThread.java

```
public class MyThread extends Thread
{
private int nb ;

public MyThread (int nb)
    {
    this.nb = nb ;
    }

public void run ()
    {
    try
        {
        for(int i=0 ; i<nb ; i++)
            {
            System.out.print ("test "+i+"\n");
            sleep (500);
            }
        }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }
}
```

So i just would like to :
AddTxt("test "+i+"\n");
instead of :
System.out.print ("test "+i+"\n");
But of course, it doesn't works.
Regards.

Comment: You need a reference to your Fenetre object- you could pass one into the constructor and store in an instance variable- just like you are doing with your nb instance var (although that's not a reference of course)- or add an injector (eg setFenetre)

Answer (score 2):

Pass `Fenetre` object to thread, so that you can access the object in run method.
In run method, let us assume the `fe` is the object of `Fenetre`.

```
public void run ()
    {
    try
        {
        for(int i=0 ; i<nb ; i++)
            {
            System.out.print ("test "+i+"\n");
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
                    new Runnable()
                    {
                       fe.AddTxt("test "+i+"\n");
                    });sleep (500);
            }
        }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }
```

Comment: Ok, it works fine with :  public MyThread (int nb,Fenetre fe)
  {
     this.nb = nb ;
     this.fen=fe;
     }

Comment: Yes, In this way, we need to pass `Fenetre` object to thread object

Answer (score 1):

> So i just would like to : AddTxt("test "+i+"\n"); instead of : System.out.print ("test "+i+"\n"); But of course, it doesn't works. Regards.

It can't work because your Thread-class doesn't know your Frame-class.

```
public class MyThread extends Thread
{
private int nb ;

private Fenetre fen;

public void setFenetre(final Fenetre fen) {
   this.fen = fen;
}

public MyThread (int nb)
    {
    this.nb = nb ;
    }

public void run ()
    {
    try
        {
        for(int i=0 ; i<nb ; i++)
            {
            fen.AddText ("test "+i+"\n");
            sleep (500);
            }
        }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }
}
```

> 

```
public class MaFenetre
{
public static void main (String args[])
    {
    Fenetre fen = new Fenetre() ;
    fen.setVisible(true) ;

    MyThread test = new MyThread (15) ;
    test.setFenetre(fen);
    test.start() ;      
    }
}
```